# Kotlin serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I have class:

```
data class Item(
    ...,
    val shop: Multimap<Long, List<Long>>?,
    ...
)
```

Part of my json:

"shop":{"3":[1,2,3,4,27,28,29,30,31],"4":[4,27,28,29,30,31]}

I am using custom serializer:

```
@Serializable(with = Multimap.Serializer::class)
data class Multimap<K, V>(val pairs: List<Pair<K, V>>?) {
    class Serializer<K, V>(val kSerializer: KSerializer<K>, val vSerializer: KSerializer<V>) :
        KSerializer<Multimap<K, V>> {
        override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = MapSerializer(kSerializer, vSerializer).descriptor

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Multimap<K, V>) {
            encoder.encodeCollection(descriptor, value.pairs!!.size) {
                value.pairs.forEachIndexed { i, (k, v) ->
                    encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * i, kSerializer, k)
                    encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * i + 1, vSerializer, v)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Multimap<K, V> {
            val pairs = decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
                if (decodeSequentially()) {
                    val size = decodeCollectionSize(descriptor)
                    List(size / 2) {
                        val k = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * it, kSerializer)
                        val v = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * it + 1, vSerializer)
                        k to v
                    }
                } else {
                    buildList {
                        while (true) {
                            val i = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)
                            if (i == CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE) break
                            val k = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, i, kSerializer)
                            val j = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)
                            if (j == CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE) throw SerializationException("missing value")
                            val v = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, j, vSerializer)
                            add(k to v)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Multimap(pairs)
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but sometimes that part of json looks like:

```
"shop":[]
```

and I get an error:

```
Unexpected JSON token at offset 6556: Expected start of the object '{', but had ':' instead at path: $.item_list[14].shop
```

Comment: JSON syntax `[]` is for a list. That looks like "shop" can sometimes be a map and other times a list.

Comment: sure. But how can I deal with that?

Comment: `Multimap<Long, List<Long>>` is weird. Did you mean `Multimap<Long, Long>` or `Map<Long, List<Long>>`? Those both map one key to many values, instead of mapping one key to many lists.

Comment: in this case MultiMap is only a name of my own class and which suit for the purpose (except issue I described)

Comment: Where does `"shop": []` comes from ? Is that produced by your serializer ?

Answer (score 1):

If you require to allow an empty *list* for shop body, you can add a safety block/corner case at the start of your deserializer, to try to decode an empty list:

```
// Check if multimap is encoded as en empty list. If so, return an empty Multimap.
// Otherwise, silence the error and try to deserialize the map as usual 
val listDescriptor = ListSerializer(serializer<String>()).descriptor
kotlin.runCatching {
    decoder.decodeStructure(listDescriptor) {
        if (decodeCollectionSize(serializer<String>().descriptor) > 1) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Only empty list are accepted.")
        }
    }
}.onSuccess { return Multimap(emptyList()) }
```

With that, you can decode `{ "shop": [] }`.

Full reproducible example below. The only changes from your code are:

1. I added the above snippet at the start of your deserializer
2. I fixed the potential NPE on `value.pairs!!.size`

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.builtins.ListSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.builtins.MapSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

@Serializable
data class Item(val shop: Multimap<Long, List<Long>>?)

@Serializable(with = Multimap.Serializer::class)
data class Multimap<K, V>(val pairs: List<Pair<K, V>>?) {
    class Serializer<K, V>(val kSerializer: KSerializer<K>, val vSerializer: KSerializer<V>) :
        KSerializer<Multimap<K, V>> {
        override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = MapSerializer(kSerializer, vSerializer).descriptor

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Multimap<K, V>) {
            encoder.encodeCollection(descriptor, value.pairs?.size ?: 0) {
                value.pairs?.forEachIndexed { i, (k, v) ->
                    encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * i, kSerializer, k)
                    encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * i + 1, vSerializer, v)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Multimap<K, V> {
            // Check if multimap is encoded as en empty list. If so, return an empty Multimap.
            // Otherwise, silence the error and try to deserialize the map as usual 
            val listDescriptor = ListSerializer(serializer<String>()).descriptor
            kotlin.runCatching {
                decoder.decodeStructure(listDescriptor) {
                    if (decodeCollectionSize(serializer<String>().descriptor) > 1) {
                        throw IllegalArgumentException("Only empty list are accepted.")
                    }
                }
            }.onSuccess { return Multimap(emptyList()) }

            val pairs = decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
                if (decodeSequentially()) {
                    val size = decodeCollectionSize(descriptor)
                    List(size / 2) {
                        val k = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * it, kSerializer)
                        val v = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2 * it + 1, vSerializer)
                        k to v
                    }
                } else {
                    buildList {
                        while (true) {
                            val i = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)
                            if (i == CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE) break
                            val k = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, i, kSerializer)
                            val j = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)
                            if (j == CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE) throw SerializationException("missing value")
                            val v = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, j, vSerializer)
                            add(k to v)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Multimap(pairs)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(Json.decodeFromString<Item>("{ \"shop\":[]}"))
    println(Json.decodeFromString<Item>("""
        {
            "shop":{
                "3": [1,2,3,4,27,28,29,30,31],
                "4": [4,27,28,29,30,31]
            } 
        }
    """.trimIndent()))

    val item = Item(shop = Multimap(listOf(1L to listOf(1L), 1L to listOf(2L), 2L to listOf(3L))))
    println(Json.encodeToString(item))
    println(Json.encodeToString(Item(shop = null)))
    println(Json.encodeToString(Item(shop = Multimap(null))))
    println(Json.encodeToString(Item(shop = Multimap(emptyList()))))
}
```

Its output:

```
Item(shop=Multimap(pairs=[]))
Item(shop=Multimap(pairs=[(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]), (4, [4, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31])]))
{"shop":{"1":[1],"1":[2],"2":[3]}}
{"shop":null}
{"shop":{}}
{"shop":{}}
```